# Get text data from html page via Nutch and store in Solr

Tags: apache, solr, web-crawler, nutch

I configured **apache-nutch-1.12** and **solr-4.6**

The problem is that In Solr, arrive all fields except "content". I would like to put in "content" field, all text of html page.

In apache-nutch-1.12/conf/solrindex-mapping.xml, I have added two fields: "description" and "keywords".

```
<mapping>
  <fields>
    <field dest="description" source="metatag.description"/>
    <field dest="keywords" source="metatag.keywords"/>
    <field dest="content" source="content"/>
    <field dest="title" source="title"/>
    <field dest="host" source="host"/>
    <field dest="segment" source="segment"/>
    <field dest="boost" source="boost"/>
    <field dest="digest" source="digest"/>
    <field dest="tstamp" source="tstamp"/>
  </fields>
  <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
</mapping>
```

In Solr scheme.xml I have added two fields: "description" and "keywords".

```
<fields>
 <field name="description" type="text_general" stored="true" indexed="true" multiValued="true"/>
 <field name="keywords" type="text_general" stored="true" indexed="true" multiValued="true"/>
 ...

 <field name="content" type="text_general" stored="true" indexed="true"/>
 ...
</fields>
```

In nutch-site.xml:

```
<property>
 <name>http.agent.name</name>
 <value>My Nutch Spider</value>
</property>
<property>
 <name>plugin.includes</name>
 <value>protocol-http|urlfilter-regex|parse-(html|tika|metatags)|index-(basic|anchor|metadata)|indexer-solr|scoring-opic|urlnormalizer-(pass|regex|basic)</value> 
 </property>
 <property>
  <name>metatags.names</name>
 <value>description,keywords</value>
</property>
<property>
 <name>index.parse.md</name>
 <value>metatag.description,metatag.keywords</value>
</property>
<property>
 <name>index.metadata</name>
 <value>description,keywords</value>
</property>
```

**Running:**

```
bin/crawl -i -D solr.server.url=http://localhost:8080/solr/argentina urls/argentina.txt crawler/argentina  1
```

and in solr the "content" field is empty.

**Response Example from Solr:**

```
{
 "responseHeader":{
 "status":0,
 "QTime":1,
 "params":{
 "indent":"true",
      "q":"*:*",
      "wt":"json",
      "rows":"1000"}},
 "response":{"numFound":28,"start":0,"docs":[
    {
        "tstamp":"2016-11-24T11:08:13.743Z",
        "description":["My perfect description"],
        "segment":"20161124120734",
        "digest":"a449c62842cb0c461ec831a683642af3",
        "boost":1.0,
        "id":"http://www.my-beauty-site.org/argentina",
        "keywords":["myKey1, myKey2, myKey3"],
        "url":"http://www.my-beauty-site.org/argentina",
        "content":"",
        "_version_":1551877664131776512
    },
    ... ... ....
    }
}
```

Then, 
I run the following command to read the data in the segment:

```
bin/nutch readseg -dump crawler/argentina/segments/* argentinaDirectory -nocontent -nofetch -nogenerate -noparse -noparsedata
```

end in the argentinaDirectory/dump file the "ParseText" field is always empty.

```
Recno:: 0
URL:: http://www.my-beauty-site.org/argentina
ParseText::

Recno:: 1
URL:: ... ... 
...
```

Comment: Can you share the output of the `parsechecker` command? `bin/nutch parsechecker <url>` Usually this should output all the parsed data from the given URL, also try the `indexchecker` command which should show what data is going to be indexed